# Equivalence relation $\varsigma$ on ${\mathbb{R}}^2$

Tags: graph-theory, relations

How to show that there is exist *equivalence relation* $\varsigma$  on ${\mathbb{R}}^2$ such that the following conditions  hold:

1. Exist only $7$ equivalence classes by  $\varsigma$.
2. For every $x,y \in {\mathbb{R}}^2$ if the distance between $x$ and $y$ is $1$, then $x,y$ are in different equivalence classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem) on this problem:

> The upper bound of seven on the chromatic number follows from the existence of a tessellation of the plane by regular hexagons, with diameter slightly less than one, that can be assigned seven colors in a repeating pattern to form a 7-coloring of the plane; according to Soifer (2008), this upper bound was first observed by John R. Isbell.

There's a picture of the colouring in the article, but stackexchange seems to not support svg for some reason.

Comment: Great! Thanks!!